# Spring Data JDBC - @Column annotation does't work on setter

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I need to convert entity's field on fetch and according to [this official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/cb8a696d4347169cbfdaf7a2ec1938c7969e95f4/jdbc/basics/src/main/java/example/springdata/jdbc/basics/aggregate/LegoSet.java#L65) I've tried to do that with custom setter:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;


@Table("entity")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(builderClassName = "EntityBuilder")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private String someId;

    @Transient
    private String entityName;

    @Column("entity_name")
    public String getEntityNameUnmodified() {
        return this.entityName;
    }

    @Column("entity_name")
    public void setEntityNameUnmodified(String em) {
        this.entityName = em + " Some modification";
    }
}
```

But this completely doesn't work and as a result I get `Entity` with `entityName == null`.

I've downloaded GitHub example and run it locally and everything worked. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My code didn't work because of missing `@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)` annotation.

Working solution:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.AccessType;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;


@Table("entity")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(builderClassName = "EntityBuilder")
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY) // IMPORTANT !!!
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private String someId;

    @Transient
    private String entityName;

    @Column("entity_name")
    public String getEntityNameUnmodified() {
        return this.entityName;
    }

    @Column("entity_name")
    public void setEntityNameUnmodified(String em) {
        this.entityName = em + " Some modification";
    }
}
```

The thing is that Spring Data JDBC uses fields as accessors for entity's columns by default and without that annotation setters and getters are ignored. Enabling `PROPERTY` access type solves the problem.